# How do you trace "foo.exe: <socket: 23>: hWaitForInput: end of file"?

Tags: haskell, exception

I'm getting the following error in my terminal: `foo.exe: <socket: 23>: hWaitForInput: end of file`. When I run foo.exe with `-xc` (after compiling with `-prof`) it doesn't appear to be an exception. I do see other exceptions generating stack trace, e.g. `*** Exception (reporting due to +RTS -xc): (THUNK), stack trace:`.

Any ideas on how I could trace where this is coming from? I suspect it is in the TCP stack or something related, but manually hunting through dependencies could be difficult.

According to the documentation for `hWaitForInput`:

This operation may fail with: `isEOFError` if the end of file has been reached.
This has type `isEOFError :: IOError -> Bool`, so it appears the error may be absolved, though I'm not sure why I'm seeing output on the terminal indicating an error, in that case.

**Update**

Here is what *may* be the stack trace:

```
*** Exception (reporting due to +RTS -xc): (THUNK), stack trace:
  UnliftIO.Exception.finally.\.\,
  called from UnliftIO.Exception.finally.\,
  called from UnliftIO.Exception.finally,
  called from Control.Concurrent.HierarchyInternal.newChild.\,
  called from Control.Concurrent.HierarchyInternal.newChild,
  called from FDS.Servers.Proto.acceptThreadMapped.safeForkIO,
  called from UnliftIO.Exception.withException.\.\,
  called from UnliftIO.Exception.withException.\,
  called from UnliftIO.Exception.withException,
  called from UnliftIO.Exception.onException,
  called from FDS.Servers.Proto.acceptThreadMapped.\,
  called from FDS.Servers.Proto.acceptThreadMapped,
  called from FDS.Servers.Proto.serveThreadMapped.\,
  called from FDS.Servers.Proto.serveThreadMapped,
  called from FDS.Servers.Proto.serveTBQ.\,
  called from FDS.Servers.Proto.serveTBQ,
  called from FDS.Servers.Proto.protoServe.enQserver,
  called from FDS.Servers.Proto.protoServe,
  called from Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.>>=.\.(...),
  called from Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.liftIO,
  called from Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.>>=.\,
  called from Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.>>=,
  called from Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.runResourceT.\.\,
  called from Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.runResourceT.\,
  called from Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.runResourceT,
  called from UnliftIO.Exception.bracket.\.\,
  called from UnliftIO.Exception.bracket.\,
  called from UnliftIO.Exception.bracket,
  called from FDS.Data.FarmPCMessage.protoReceiver,
  called from RIO.Prelude.RIO.askUnliftIO.\.\,
  called from RIO.Prelude.RIO.askUnliftIO.\,
  called from RIO.Prelude.RIO.askUnliftIO,
  called from Control.Monad.IO.Unlift.withRunInIO.\,
  called from Control.Monad.IO.Unlift.withRunInIO,
  called from UnliftIO.Exception.catch.\,
  called from UnliftIO.Exception.mask.\.\,
  called from UnliftIO.Exception.mask.\,
  called from Control.Monad.IO.Unlift.withRunInIO,
  called from UnliftIO.Exception.catch,
  called from UnliftIO.Exception.catchAny,
  called from FDS.Config.Core.retryForever,
  called from Main.main
FarmDataServer.exe: <socket: 23>: hWaitForInput: end of file
```

`acceptThreadMapped` looks like this, which does not directly call `hWaitForInput`:

```
acceptThreadMapped
  :: MonadUnliftIO m
  => ThreadMap -- ^ ThreadMap where newly created thread will be registered.
  -> NS.Socket -- ^ Listening and bound socket.
  -> ((NS.Socket, NS.SockAddr) -> IO ())
  -- ^ Computation to run in a different thread once an incoming connection is
  -- accepted. Takes the connection socket and remote end address.
  -> m ThreadId
acceptThreadMapped tMap lsock k = liftIO $ mask $ \restore -> do
  (csock, addr) <- restore (NS.accept lsock)
  onException
     (safeForkIO (finally (restore (k (csock, ipv4mapped_to_ipv4 addr)))
                         (TCP.closeSock csock)))
     (TCP.closeSock csock)
  where
    safeForkIO ioAction = newChild tMap (\_ -> ioAction)
```

Comment: A sensible first question would be, where are you using hWaitForInput?

Comment: I'm not using directly, which is why I'm trying to trace it. Most likely it is coming from some TCP related function that I'm using. So I can narrow it down slightly.

Comment: I added what might be the relevant stack trace, as well as what might be some related code.

Comment: I guess the most likely culprit given the information shown here is `k`. You'll have to look at the caller to see what that is.

Comment: Ah, I guess the forked thread makes it impossible to view the stacktrace passed the fork.